# What is Safari's AutoFillCorrections.db file?

Tags: macos, safari, backup, time-machine

Safari has a file called `/Users/King/Library/Safari/AutoFillCorrections.db`. It is sizably large and keeps changing a few times every hour. I'm thinking of excluding this from my Time Machine backup, as it takes up a fair bit of space. However, I am unsure of whether this will have any adverse effects when I restore from my Time Machine backup.

For what it's worth, all my passwords and history are synced with iCloud, and the normal autofill information comes from my Contacts app, so I have no need to keep any autofill information. I'm not sure however of the exact reason this file exists.